# How long does therapeutic mRNA last in vivo?

Tags: rna, mrna

How long does mRNA delivered therapeutically to cells last in the human cell once it's gotten there? I've seen sources say that endogenous mRNA lasts around 8-10 hours in humans, but wasn't sure if anything about the currently used mRNA therapeutics extended their halflife in vivo. For example, some of the COVID vaccines used a human α-globin fragment for one of their UTRs, and similar specifically selected UTRs show up in mRNA therapeutics presumably to enhance either transcription or stability.

Comment: This is a very broad question which is unlikely to be answered in this form. Can you please restrict yourself to one question at a time?

Comment: @Chris Understood, question scope restricted, thanks

Comment: mRNA half-life varies markedly, with a variety of stabilising features (or the reverse). Viral structural RNAs that act as mRNA differ again. Regardless, mRNAs are not transcribed. If you want to know how long a particular viral RNA or a particular vaccine RNA persists, that would be a valid question. Likewise the purpose of introducing particular sequences in vaccines. But at the moment your question seems to me misconceived.